# Android 2.3.3 (API level 8) AsyncTask weirdness

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I Have several activities handling diferent screens with information that is loaded asynchrounously via AsyncTask.

All data fetching are done in doInBackground()
All UI operations are done in onPostExecute()

In some instances I get the error: "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"

If I do the Looper.prepare(), it crashes if a new activity is instanced for this class.

It's a weird behaviour that I'm able to find why it happens. The other screens with similar behaviour work as expected. There are no differences between them that I can find.

Has anyone had this behaviour?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Do you cancel your asynctask(s) when you switch between activities? It's a common mistake not to do it...

Comment: MrYanDao, for confidentiality issues I cannot post the code.

Comment: Sounds like you create Handler objects for the AsyncTask thread. Is that intended?

Comment: BTW, regarding the title _Android 2.3.3 (API level 8)_: API level 8 would be Android 2.2; Android 2.3.3 would be API level 10.

Comment: I've incorrecly placed API Level 8 but meant 10.

Comment: I'm not creating the Handler objects for the AsyncTask thread.
The initial code was not written by me and has a lot, and I mean a huge lot, of errors and awfully written code. I'm trying to trace all issues and fix them one by one, as requested by the customer, instead of just writting the whole app from scratch.

By following the code, I'm finding that all async are being constructed on the UI Thread but the code is sometimes hard to follow.

Answer (score 1):

"Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()" means that you are trying to call `AsyncTask.execute()` outside of the UI thread.

There are few rules you should follow using `AsyncTask`:

- The task instance must be created on the UI thread.
- execute(Params...) must be invoked on the UI thread.

Also it can mean than you are creating `Handler` object inside `doInBackground` method.